# How to inline navbar elemens

Tags: html, css

I am styling the navbar my simple side with the following code:

Html:

```
<div>
  <ul class="navbar-brand">
    <a href='https://postimg.org/image/ukcombaed/' target='_blank'><img src='https://s10.postimg.org/7vnhmqt0p/IMG_20160804_WA032.jpg' border='0' alt='IMG-20160804-WA032'/><br /><a target='_blank' href='https://postimage.org/'>    </a><br /><br />
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-right">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about</li>
    <li>delivery</li>
    <li>services</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  width:100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul.navbar-brand{
  float:left;
}
ul.navbar-right{
  float:right;
}
```

As my snippet shows( https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/t3uhg5n1/1/ ). The logo is floated to the left and the menu to the right as I want. But the problem is that the menu went the top and would actually like it to be positioned to the bottom.
How can I actually make the menu go to the bottom instead and keep it floated to the right?

Answer (score 1):

I can see few issues:

1. For 1st a tag there is no closing of it
2. You can remove 2nd a if you are not using
3. ul can't be used with li so, changed it to div or span
4. Remove float:right from navbar-right class it will come in the bottom of logo.
5. add a ul class with magin, padding 0

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 0;
}
ul.navbar-brand{
  float:left;
}
ul.navbar-right{
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a href='https://postimg.org/image/ukcombaed/' target='_blank'><img src='https://s10.postimg.org/7vnhmqt0p/IMG_20160804_WA032.jpg' border='0' alt='IMG-20160804-WA032'/></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar-right">
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about</li>
    <li>delivery</li>
    <li>services</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @I just edited my question for better understanding.
Did not mean to say that the menu should be placed after the image.
I would simply like to move the menu down the position where it is,but keeping it floated to the right.
Hope I made some sense

Comment: do you have any picture or screenshot for more clarity on the expectation?

Comment: I f you check on this theme http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/59038.html,which is not exactly the same since there the menu is not floated to the right. The menu and the LOGO are displayed in the same line and the menu is positioned to the bottom. Mine in contrast is positioned further to the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.navbar-right{
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to edit your existing answer with this information?

Comment: can you update the existing code. will make changes into that